# Change the color of the cursor in Sublime Text

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime Text the dark theme. The problem is that my cursor is also black and I can't see where it is with my background being black. How can I change my cursor color without change any color characteristics of my theme.

Comment: Hi, to customize your settings in sublime text Select Preferences-> "Settings-Default". This will open the default settings tab. Look for the word "caret" - and try changing the options related to caret. Now go back to your custom setting and update as per your choice....

Comment: @Devid I can't edit the *Settings-Default*, either way I want to change the color which according to http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13974 I should edit the color scheme.

Answer (score 10):

If you are speaking of the dark I-beam cursor in windows, then this is not a sublimetext setting.  Change it in the mouse pointers section. Change "Text Select" to "beam_r.cur" which is easily visible in a dark themed sublimetext.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where is the mouse pointers section at?

Comment: @Weezy, Windows Control Panel, Mouse settings, Pointers tab, Modify the "Select Text" mouse pointer.

Answer (score 2):

To customize your settings in Sublime Text Select "Preferences" → "Settings-Default". This will open the default settings tab. Look for the word "caret" and try changing the options related to caret. Now go back to your custom setting and update as per your choice.
Follow the following link to be more precise [http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15219].
Put a comment if you have any questions...

Answer (score 1):

I found out this solution, having the same error as you:

[HTML Color Picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)

1. Install Packages: "PackageResourceViewer" and "BlockCursorEverywhere"
2. Go to "PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource"
3. Search in your *theme package* a file named ".tmTheme", this file is usually found in your *user settings* as "color_scheme" value.
4. Add the following XML section (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Block%20Cursor%20Everywhere) in your theme file:

   ```
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>Block Cursor</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>block_cursor</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>#000000</string>
           <key>background</key>
           <string>#FF1111</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```
5. Change the "background" string value (FF1111) use the HTML color picker from above, save it and the cursor colour should change at the moment.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In ST3, according to https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html#customization

This is just a matter of creating a dedicated customization file to provide your overridden settings.