# Change cursor color in sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Im trying to change the cursor color in sublime text. Im running windows in a VM on my mac.

In Preferences.sublime-settings ive added the following but it hasn't done anything:

```
// Change caret colour? 
"caret_color": "#FF0000",

"caret": "#FF0000",
```

This is similar to this question but the answer there doenst work for me: [Change the color of the cursor in Sublime Text](https://superuser.com/questions/799892/change-the-color-of-the-cursor-in-sublime-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caret color is defined in the color scheme you are using. Since you have Sublime Text 2, changing the color scheme is quite straightforward. First, open your user preferences and check the value of `"color_scheme"` to get the path to the scheme you're using. If you haven't set it there, the default value is `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme`. Next, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder in your file system explorer. Browse to the location of the color scheme and open the corresponding `.tmTheme` file in Sublime, using XML as the syntax highlighting. Near the top of the file, you'll see something like the following (taken from the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme)):

```xml
<key>name</key>
<string>Neon</string>
<key>settings</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>activeGuide</key>
            <string>#FF0080</string>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#000000</string>
            <key>caret</key>
            <string>#FFFFFF</string>
            <key>findHighlight</key>
            <string>#F2FF06</string>
            <key>findHighlightForeground</key>
            <string>#1515FF</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FFFFFF</string>
            <key>guide</key>
            <string>#6F6F6F</string>
            <key>inactiveSelection</key>
            <string>#353576</string>
            <key>invisibles</key>
            <string>#06FF05</string>
            <key>lineHighlight</key>
            <string>#2D2D2D</string>
            <key>searchHighlight</key>
            <string>#0205FF</string>
            <key>selection</key>
            <string>#0205FF</string>
            <key>selectionBorder</key>
            <string>#06FF05</string>
            <key>stackGuide</key>
            <string>#06FF05</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Find the `caret` key:

```xml
<key>caret</key>
<string>#FFFFFF</string>
```

and change its value to whatever hex color code you want. If there is no `caret` key, you can add it.

Once you're done, save the file. Go back to your file explorer and delete the color scheme's `.tmTheme.cache` file if it exists. Restart Sublime, and your changes should take effect.

Comment: Thats is changing the color of the blinking line in the text that shows me where I am, however its not changing the mouse cursor.

Comment: @jdln You didn't indicate in your question you were trying to change the mouse cursor. You need to set that in your Windows configuration settings - Sublime has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @MattDMo caret is not cursor, two different words.

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov In the US, at least, the two words are often used interchangeably. The OP also mentioned `caret` settings in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use vintage mode there are two caret types, `block_caret` and `caret`.  `block_caret` is probably used outside of vintage mode as well but thought it would be worth mentioning.  While this post is tagged for sublime text version 2 it is 8 years old and it was the top result when searching for this issue.  I fixed mine by editing my color scheme and adding

```
    "globals":
    {
        "block_caret": "hsla(210, 13%, 40%, 0.08)",
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.. Following worked for me.

Use this article to get to mouse settings, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14203/windows-7-make-mouse-easier-to-use.

I chose the "Regular Black" option, which inspite of the name, is surprisingly easy to see in Sublime

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sublime preferences from

Select "Preferences" → "Settings-Default". 
Go to Default settings tab
change the options related to caret. 
Now go back to your custom setting and update as per your choice.

Please refer [This](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15219]#p57536) link , which will be helpful

Comment: This is where iver put my code from my question but nothing changes.